# Load QGIS Server (qgs) fed WFS/WMS data and new qgs project files into OWC2

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client, qwc2

The new docker-based project - https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-docker is great.

When I try to load a WMS/WFS service from QGIS Server, I get no response.

http://xxx:8015/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?VERSION=1.3.0&map=D:/Projects/QGIS/CCRC.qgs
[image]

**How do I add this?**